# Create a list of a discriminate union type with 3 different primitive types

Tags: types, syntax, f#, discriminated-union

So I am attempting to create a list of a discriminate union type such as;

```
type ColType = Int of int | Float of float | String of string
```

And then insert into a list, such as

```
let addToList (list : ColType list) (col : ColType) =
let list' = list @[col]
list'
```

However I am unsure how to initialize the coltype values as I only get values such as int -> coltype etc.

I tried this function

```
let createColType x = 
    if x.GetType() = int then  
        Int x
    else if x.GetType() = float then 
        Float x 
    else if x.GetType() = string then  
        String x
    else 
        String x
```

Which obviously doesnt work as it will return different values, so how would you go about solving this?

Comment: How do you use createColType function? Do you use it for typed values or for values of type obj?

Comment: What does your int, float, and string represent? Why don't you want to permit a decimal? If these represent business constraints you might want to consider giving these real names that align to your business needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `match` to check multiple options and `:?` to match the type:

```
let createColType x = 
    match box x with
    | :? int    as i -> ColType.I i
    | :? float  as f -> ColType.F f
    | :? string as s -> ColType.S s
    |_-> failwithf "Type not supported %A" <| x.GetType().FullName

createColType  1  |> printfn "%A" // shows:  I 1
createColType  2. |> printfn "%A" // shows:  F 2.0
createColType "3" |> printfn "%A" // shows:  S "3"
```

Comment: The type test pattern match used here is the right approach. But I would generally prefer to return a result type using `Ok` and `Error` rather than throwing an exception. Then any code that calls this function can decide whether a unsupported type is worth throwing an exception for and potentially blowing up the app.

Comment: I'm highly skeptical that their actual types are String, Int, Float. Also the DU prevents the need for any failwith in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Food = Hamburgers of int | Soda of float | Other of string 
module Food = 
    let tryCreate food = 
        match box food with
        | :? int as i -> Some(Hamburgers i)
        | :? float as f -> Some(Soda f)
        | :? string as s -> Some(Other s)
        | _ -> None

let burgers = Hamburgers 7
let soda = Soda 3.2
let mozzarellaSticks = Other "Mozzarella Sticks"
let mysteryMeat = Option.toList(Food.tryCreate "nobody knows")

let list = [burgers; soda; mozzarellaSticks] @ mysteryMeat
```

By using an `Option` as the return type for my `tryCreate` I will not get any runtime exception. You'll notice also that I've tried to create DU labels that associate with my business goals. This makes it easier to express intent, and makes the unions more useful than simple ints, strings, and floats. Most of the time I know what type I have because the type corresponds to a business use, so I don't have to write or use a tryCreate. Often in practice it's not meaningfully possible to map primitives to our discriminated unions, consider for example if we added a `| Hotdogs of int` it's ambiguous if any int we add is a hotdog or a hamburger.