# Init an discriminated union of different data types with a single constructor

Tags: types, f#, discriminated-union

say I have a type such as:

```
type Variedvalue = I of int| S of string | F of float
```

Is there a way to create a function which takes in a generic parameter which initializes the correct field of the union?

i.e something like

```
with static member initVariedValue (x : 'a) = 
   match x.getType() with  
   | int -> VariedValue.I x 
   | float -> VariedValue.F x
   | String -> VariedVAlue.S x
```

This doesnt work, even if I inline it as the generic variable is inferred to be int in this case thus will never reach the float or string conditional.
So is there some clever way to do this or do I simply have to create a constructor for each field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a list of a discriminate union type with 3 different primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256962/create-a-list-of-a-discriminate-union-type-with-3-different-primitive-types)

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but in brief, the F# type system won't allow you to do what you're trying to do. It's usually counterproductive (and often impossible) to fight the type system; instead, figure out what you're *really* trying to do and find a way to achieve that. Also, when you mention creating a constructor for each field, did you know that `I`, `S` and `F` *are* constructors? Try it. Paste your `VariedValue` definition into F# Interactive and then type `F;;`, and you'll see that `F` is a function of type `float -> VariedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  However, you will need to support the case when an unexpected type is passed into your constructor function.  I would do this by returning a `Result<VariedValue, 'e>` instead of returning a `VariedValue` directly.  Alternatively, you could throw in the unhandled case, but that would break expected behavior for a constructor in my opinion.

```
type VariedValue = I of int| S of string | F of float

module VariedValue =
    let init (x: 'a) =
        match box x with
        | :? int as i -> I i |> Ok
        | :? string as s -> S s |> Ok
        | :? float as f -> F f |> Ok
        | _ -> Error <| sprintf "Unsupported VariedValue Type: %s" (x.GetType().Name)
```

Examples:

```
> VariedValue.init 3;;
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<VariedValue,string> = Ok (I 3)

> VariedValue.init <| System.Guid.NewGuid();;
[<Struct>]
val it : Result<VariedValue,string> =
  Error "Unsupported VariedValue Type: Guid"
```